# Strike rotation in cricket

Tags: cricket, terminology

If the batsman hits the ball to the keepers helmet which is placed behind the keeper,( which gives 5 runs,) for the last ball of the over then rotation of the strike involves or not?????

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in [Law 41 section 3](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-41-the-fielder/). It states:

*If a protective helmet belonging to the fielding side is on the ground within the field of play, and the ball while in play strikes it, the ball 
shall become dead and, except in the 
circumstances of Law 34 (Hit the ball twice), 
5 penalty runs shall then be awarded to 
the batting side, in addition to the penalty for a No ball or a Wide, if applicable.

Additionally runs completed by the batsmen before the ball strikes 
the protective helmet shall be scored, together with the run in progress if the batsmen had already crossed at the 
instant of the ball striking the protective helmet.
See Law 18.10 (Runs scored when the 
ball becomes dead other than at the fall of a wicket).*

This means that if the batsmen crossed for a run, they remain in their positions as of when the helmet was struck.

So, to answer your specific question, rotation does take place, if it's required.